# Launching the Aurasma & QR Scanner app from mobile web browser (Chrome)

Tags: android, google-chrome, qr-code, aurasma

I have built a website which will be used at a brand launch event as the user dashboard. Each user will get an android tablet and the browser with the website will be locked as the main screen.

From there I have 2 links which they need to click on to access: Aurasma, and a QR code scanner.

I am wondering if there is a simple, clean solution for when they click the logo image that the app will launch on their tablet.I have tried all the other solutions and jQuery plug in and googled as much as I could but nothing worked.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-center"> 
<p>Aurasma Scanner</p><hr>
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/aurasma_logo.png"></img>

</div>
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 text-center">
<p>Qr Code Scanner</p><hr>
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.scan.android.client&hl=en" target="_blank"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/qr_logo.png"></img></a>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Any URL starting `aurasma:` should open the Aurasma app.

Also, any `http://auras.ma/s/xxxxx` Aura share link (generated in-app or via Aurasma Studio) should also open the app, and cause the app to pre-load the shared content. Note that "screenshot" share links have the same format, but will open in the browser instead.

Note also that Aurasma has a built-in QR scanner, so you don't need a separate app for that.

Comment: Sorry can someone elaborate on this answer - 

1 - please clarify 'aura share link' - what is the format for that? I know how to access auras in the usual way but not via a url. if that is possible, Id like to know. 
2 - please clarify 'screenshot share link'. What are they? What is the format?

Im trying to launch the native browser from Aurasma and it seems impossible. Perhaps knowing the format of these urls will help me devise some sort of workaround.

Comment: @Boshy `I'm trying to launch the native browser from Aurasma` - that's the complete opposite of this question.

Comment: Yes I do realise he is asking about loading aurasma from a url but you then respond with what appears to be possibly interesting info. Sorry I just wanted clarity on what you hint at but seem to assume we all know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Boshy what do you imagine I'm hinting at? The share link is the link you get when you share something. If you have a separate question then ask it properly, though I'm pretty sure you open the native browser by tapping the open in browser button.

Comment: OK: 
1. the guy here wants to know how to open aurasma from a link. Thats useful and part of what Im doing. 
2. You *imply* that you know how to obtain a url that directly links to an aura - Ive never seen that and did not know it was possible. You then talk about screenshot share links working 'in the same format' - what format? As the aurasma link, or some other?
3. No, it is impossible to open a native browser from Aurasma, all urls open in the Aurasma browser, even though it offers 'open in native browser' it is quite well documented that this does not work.
4. Im sorry Im so thick.

Comment: You obtain share links via the app or Aurasma Studio (there's a share button somewhere), as the answer says. I believe it actually shares the entire channel (though channels are well hidden in the UI). The format is `http://auras.ma/s/xxxxx`, as the answer says. As for "it is quite well documented that this does not work", it worked when I wrote it. I guess someone broke it in the last couple of years.

Comment: I think we're now talking at criss purposes so not to worry. Enjoy your day.